# Sybase ASE to Oracle Database replication

Tags: oracle, sybase, database-replication, sap-ase

Hope you all are doing great,

I'm really new to sybase but I tried and succeeded in ASE to ASE replication, Now I wish to create a setup for ASE to Oracle replication, so please guide me on this, ( I can find video's or text related to Oracle to ASE but the replication from ASE to ORACLE is bit different from that, so please guide me on this )

I have connected both source and target db with rep server, also created the subscription and definition for the connections,
While checking the status of the subscriptions which I have created it looks as
"Subscription VALID as primary"
"Subscription is DEFINED at replicate"

So I guess the problem must be at the target database as the subscription which I have created is just showing as DEFINED not as VALID, what may be the problem ?

Thank you in advance..

Comment: First are you using SAP Replication Server Heterogeneous edition for Oracle?

Comment: Hi Michael,

Yes, i am using the SAP Replication Server Heterogeneous edition. THank you much for considering my request.

Comment: And I assume you've done the installation steps mentioned here: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36924.1571/doc/html/san1276288005907.html

Comment: Yes Michael, I did the same as mentioned above,,And i want to add one more question here..I missed this step "ExpressConnect for Oracle (ECO) is installed with SAP Replication Server. To use ECO,
obtain the SYBASE_REP_ECO.lic static file and the README.txt file from the SPDC or
SMP Web site.
Copy this license to $SYBASE/SYSAM-2_0/licenses directory on UNIX platforms or
the %SYBASE%\SYSAM-2_0\licenses directory on Windows.
Obtaining ECO Static License
Configuration" and it looks the replication was not happened is because of this ?? pls confirm

Comment: ECO is a separate licensable feature so you need to have paid and installed the license from the SAP site as either a standalone license or onto your license server to use this feature.